# Remote error on pushing repository

Tags: git, push

I have two repository project and project2. Project2 is a clone of project repository whenever I tried to push the files from project2 I got remote errors.

```
Total 6 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree   inconsistent
remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.
remote: error:
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable t
remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing int
remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
remote: error: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in som
remote: error: other way.
remote: error:
remote: error: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, se
remote: error: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
To C:/Users/Ashish/Desktop/new_1
! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)
error: failed to push some refs to 'C:/Users/Ashish/Desktop/new_1'
```

Comment: Did you `git pull` ? If not, can you do this and show the output : `git fetch --all` then `git branch -va` ?

Comment: yes  `git pull` is working